# Remove/disable child node of a child node from a treeview (VB.NET) (what is wrong with this code?)

Tags: vb.net, treeview, treenode

I want to remove/disable child nodes after a certain number entered by user in a text box.
I know there is something wrong in following code, but I am not able to figure it out (I am a beginner).

```
Dim k As Integer
k = Val(TextBox1.Text)
For i = k + 1 To 4
TreeView1.Nodes(1).Nodes("Node" & i).Remove()
Next
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out knowing what error you are getting, or what your TreeView1 Node structure is( whether or not you have multiple root nodes. I am presuming that you are forgetting that the [TreeNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xdhazd0.aspx) Index is zero based, and should be using `TreeView1.Nodes(0)`.

From above Link:

> To assign TreeNode objects to a specific location, or to retrieve them from the TreeNodeCollection, you can reference the collection object with a specific index value. The index value of the TreeNodeCollection is a zero-based index.

The below code works for me with a node structure of:

[image]

```
Dim k As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, k) Then 'Checking if conversion is valid before trying to use 
    For i = k + 1 To 4
        TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes("Node" & i).Remove() 'Using Nodes(0) for root node.
    Next
End If
```

---

As a caveat, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but these Sub Routines I hope will get you close. The first one is recreating the Original `Treeview` by creating a node structure and then clearing the `TreeView` and adding the new nodes.
 The second Sub Routine uses a number from a TextBox, checks if the created Node would be a duplicate if not, it will add it to the TreeView. The third Sub Routine is finding the last existing node adding new nodes based the number of which is based on a TextBox input.

```
Private Sub ResetNodes()
    Dim root As TreeNode

    root = New TreeNode("Node0")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node1")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node2")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node3")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node4")

    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)
End Sub

Private Sub AddNodes()
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim duplicate As Boolean
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, k) Then
        For i = 1 To k
            For Each node As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes
                If node.Text = "Node" & i Then
                    duplicate = True
                    Exit For
                End If
                duplicate = False
            Next
            If Not duplicate Then TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Node" & i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddToExistingNodes()
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim lowIndex As Integer
    Dim highIndex As Integer

    lowIndex = TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Count + 1

    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, k) Then
        highIndex = lowIndex + k
        For i = lowIndex To highIndex
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Node" & i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @mrn was there a problem with my answer?

Comment: Came across following queries, (a) how to reset to original structure during run time? (I can add a new button for this operation) and (b) is it possible generate total number of child nodes equal to  number entered in TextBox1?

Comment: @mrn. Will add some info when I get around a pc with visual studio on it

Comment: @mrn I added 3 more examples, I am not sure if you want to add x number of additional nodes starting from the last node of the collection or create a total number of nodes including existing.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, u can search and remove

```
Private Sub Delete_Sub_TreeNod()

For Each tn As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes

            For Each tn2 As TreeNode In tn.Nodes
                If tn2.Text = "Some Value" Then
                    tn2.Remove()
                End If

            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```